# show that $C^a([0,1]) \subset C^b([0,1])$ for $0<b \le a \le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f(x)\in C^a([0,1])$, there exists $K \ge 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|^a$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]$.

Then how to show that $C^a([0,1]) \subset C^b([0,1])$ for $0<b \le a \le 1$?

I tried to show if $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K_1|x-y|^a$ holds,then $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K_2|x-y|^b$ must also hold for some $K_2$ when $0<b \le a \le 1$.

I thought $|x-y|\le 1$, then $|x-y|^a<|x-y|^b$ always hold. Thus $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K_1|x-y|^a\le K_1|x-y|^b$ always hold. 
So  $C^a([0,1]) \subset C^b([0,1])$.

I am not sure about if this is correct. Could someone kindly help me look at this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct argument. However the notation should be $C^a([0,1]) \subset C^b([0,1])$, not $C^a([0,1]) \in C^b([0,1])$

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks! I have corrected it.

Comment: The moral of the story is that a small number gets smaller when it is raised to a larger power, so Holder continuity with a larger exponent is a more stringent requirement.

Comment: @Ian Exactly. Thanks!